# target has transitive dependencies that include static frameworks:

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

we have built a flutter module which uses Firebase. it works fine in emulator

now we are trying to integrate this flutter module in existing native iOS app which also uses firebase. We are having issue with pod install

```
 The 'Pods-App' target has transitive dependencies that include static frameworks: (cloud_firestore, firebase_core, FirebaseDatabase, FirebaseAuth, FirebaseFirestore, FirebaseCore, FirebaseInstanceID, FirebaseFunctions, FirebaseMessaging, and FirebaseStorage)
```

We added this line in the native app podfile to integrate
    flutter_application_path = '/Users/username/Documents/MyApp-Flutter'
  eval(File.read(File.join(flutter_application_path, '.ios', 'Flutter', 'podhelper.rb')), binding)

We followed below steps to integrate the project
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps

We added this tag in podfile which have resolved pod install issue. But ios build has failed from flutterpluginrestraint

pre_install do |installer|
  # workaround for https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3289
    Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
  end

expecting pod install needs to be successful even when we include flutter project. i can't understand how to resolve these dependencies especially if both flutter and native app use same modules.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this issue and just now managed to build successfully in my environment. You may have resolved this yourself by now but I'll leave this for any others with the issue.

Similar to you, I got this error from pod install in the host app when including a dependency with static frameworks:

```
The 'Pods-App' target has transitive dependencies that include static frameworks: (flutter_crashlytics)
```

I was originally attempting to resolve this with the workaround that you mentioned in your post. This however caused this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Zik.png

After trying seemingly every solution on the internet, **I found success with the following steps**:

1. Remove/comment the transitive dependency workaround in the Podfile
2. Remove/comment use_frameworks! for the target in the Podfile
3. At this point I got the error "No such module 'FlutterPluginRegistrant'" coming from the respective import statement in one of my activities. Remove these imports wherever there is an error, leaving any code that relies on it.
4. Add an Objective-C bridging header and add imports for Flutter.h and GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h. Adding the latter should correct any errors stemming from the last step.
5. Run pod install
6. Build successfully

Some additional observations:

- For me this issue only presented itself in Swift based host apps. I could not reproduce this using Add2App with an Objective-C based project.
- Adding s.static_framework = true to FlutterPluginRegistrant.podspec allows the app to compile without any errors, but this is a generated file and is not a permanent solution. From what I can tell this works because only a static framework can link a static framework dependency.
- I also upgraded to CocoaPods 1.7.5 beforehand and I'm not sure if that had an effect on resolving the problem. Before upgrading, I was on 1.6.2.
- Flutter channel/version: dev v1.8.1

**Bridging-Header.h:**

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
#import <KochavaTracker.h>
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
#import <FlutterPluginRegistrant/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h>
```

**Podfile:**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

flutter_application_path = '../ios/flutter_module/'

def shared_pods
    pod 'BiometricAuthentication'
    pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'
    pod 'AppDynamicsAgent'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
    pod 'KochavaTrackeriOS'
end

target 'Target1' do
    eval(File.read(File.join(flutter_application_path, '.ios', 'Flutter', 'podhelper.rb')), binding)
    inherit! :search_paths
    shared_pods
end
```

Hopefully this helps you and some others in the same situation. I'm not very experienced with CocoaPods and iOS development, so I'll leave additional speculation up to someone that can decipher the root cause.